# What is the right triplet of characters?

Tags: combinatorics

Below you will find three questions. Answer each question in order with no spaces between them. So if the answer to the first question is a, the answer to the second question is b, and the answer to the third question is c then the solution is abc. There is no "trick", by the way. You can arrive at the solution through pure logic.

What is the third character (number, letter, or symbol) you will type to solve this?

How many different characters will you type to solve this?

What is the first character you will type to solve this?

Comment: V unir gur vzcerffvba gung gurer ner n arne raqyrff ahzore bs cbffvoyr nafjref sbe guvf chmmyr evtug ? sbe rknzcyr B2B jbexf, C2C jbexf 111 jbexf naq fb sbegu, hayrff V unir zvfhaqrefgbbq fbzrguvat - rot13

Comment: Gjb nzovthvgvrf: Qb lbh zrna *glcrf* bs punenpgref va dhrfgvba 2? Nyfb, qbrf "punenpgre lbh jvyy glcr" whfg ersre gb gur guerr-punenpgre nafjre? V pbhyq glcr "pbashfvat" ba abgrcnq naq gura erfcbaq "a9p" vs abg. -rot13

Comment: @Nobody Kweeniezagop andrfrum. Marsllchtsunisgot. SOS? X2X? .:., ???, 333, 111, IIIIXIIII, IIVII, ..., Kweenie!

Comment: GUVF GUVF GUVF GUVF

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> **c2c**
>
>  Any three-character string where the 1st and 3rd characters are the same (and are not `2`) and where the 2nd character is `2` also works. So does `111`.
>
>  I promise that I did not take hints from the comments before posting.

Comment: Your regex doesn't quite work, as ROT13(Vg qbrfa'g pbafgenva gur svefg naq guveq punenpgref gb or gur fnzr, fb jvyy zngpu n2m, d2Z, rgp. )

Comment: @fljx Oh, sorry. Better remove the regex anyway